# setting accelerated endpoint for s3 using php

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm using

```
getObjectUrl
```

to get a s3 downloadable url for my webapp.
Ive enabled accelerated transfers for the entire bucket,but no matter how i conf it, i dont see any real speed differences.

```
$bucket = 'bucketname';
$file = $_POST['file'];
$client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'eu-central-1',
    'credentials' => array(
    'key' => $s3key,
    'secret'  => $s3secret,
    'endpoint' => 'http://bucketname.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com',
    'use_accelerate_endpoint'=>true,
  )
]);
```

The url i get in return from

```
$plainUrl = $client->getObjectUrl($bucket, $file);
```

is this: `https://bucketname.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/filename.ext`

is this correct? should not the plainurl return some sort of accelerated parameter? 
My question is: am i doing this right?

Comment: You should not need to pass `endpoint`.  The resulting URL should indeed include `bucket-name.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com` and your bucket cannot have any dots in its name.  You might check whether `createPresignedRequest` returns a URL with the accelerated endpoint.

Comment: ok, thank you. and the use_accelerate_endpoint is correct? ive found 3 various implementations of it. i will try a presigned request and see if that helps.

Comment: createpresignedrequest did not return an accelerated endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to s3 documentation

> Can be enabled or disabled on individual operations by setting '@use_accelerate_endpoint' to true or false. Note: you must enable S3 Accelerate on a bucket before it can be accessed via an Accelerate endpoint.

I managed to get a signed URL request using s3 php:

```
$cmd = $client->getCommand('GetObject', [
  'Bucket' => $config['bucket'],
  'Key'    => $key,
  'ResponseContentDisposition' => 'attachment; filename=' . $download_filename,
  '@use_accelerate_endpoint' => true,
]);
$request = $client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+180 minutes');
```

I initialised the s3 client with the default minimum parameters.

```
$client = new S3Client($client_config);
```

Comment: THAT was quite the difference in speed!